# Erro ao criar base de dados em SQL Server 2005 com disco comprimido

Tags: sql-server-2005, banco-de-dados

Quando tento criar uma base-de-dados, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
>
> Create failed for Database 'basededados'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\PEDIDO.mdf" is compressed but does not reside in a read-only database or filegroup. The file must be decompressed.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5118)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.5000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5118&LinkId=20476

Isto acontece porque os discos se encontram comprimidos, não existe nenhuma forma de criar a base de dados sem descompactar os discos?

Comment: Provavelmente este caminho indicado não tem permissão de escrita, ou o arquivo `.mdf` está sem a permissão. Já deu uma verificada?

Comment: Não sei se [isto ajuda para o teu problema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173009%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), dado serem 5 passos a realizar, experimenta e diz algo.

Comment: Estou como administrador, tenho as permissões totais sobre a partição. Zuul infelizmente isso não resolve o meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além de não ser considerado uma boa prática (O IO de discos pode ser intenso num banco de dados, requerendo compressão/decompressão o tempo todo) o SSMS não está disposto a criar esse .MDF a menos que você marque seu BD (filegroups na verdade) como read-only (que neste caso serão .NDF).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190257%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)